# Selected item from listbox and display it to datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, listbox

Whenver i try to add an item from listbox to datagridview it returns system.data.datarowview

[image]
How do i display all values from database? i have a table: ItemID, ItemName ,Quantity, TransDate, ItemStatus

but i want only the id, name, quantity to be displayed in datagridview

Code to add Item from listbox to datagridview:

```
private void Checkout_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadData();
    }



    public void LoadData()
    {
        SqlConnection con = Connection.GetConnection();

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From [Inventory].[dbo].[Inventory]", con);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);



        listBox1.DataSource = dt;
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "ItemName";
        listBox1.ValueMember = "ItemID";

        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();


        foreach (var item in listBox1.SelectedItems)
        {
            int index = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells["Column1"].Value = item.ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells["Column2"].Value = item.ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells["Column3"].Value = textBox3.Text;
        }
    }





    private void buttonAddtoCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadData();
    }
```

Comment: Too broad.  Focus on the immediate problem you need help with.

Comment: I just edited it.. well anyway  i need help to display a selected item from listbox to datagridview. i want to update the xml file  for example i selected item Wallet Quantity 2  after checkout

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do is create a class (or struct, but preferably a class) `CartItem` that holds the data.

```
public class CartItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()  // For displaying the Name in a listbox
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Than, in your application create a `List<CartItem>` collection that contains the objects and assign that list to the `DataSource` property of the `DataGridView`.

```
List<CartItem> cartItems = new List<CartItem>();
dataGridView2.DataSource = cartItems;
```

Then the code for adding a new `CartItem` would be:

```
private void buttonAddcart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var newItem = new CartItem()
    {
        ID = GetNewID(),  // Implement a method that creates and returns a unique identifier
        Name = textbox_Name.Text,
        Quantity = (int)numericUpDown_Quantity.Value
    };

    cartItems.Add(newItem);
}
```

You maybe need to configure the datagrid view for displaying the correct columns, you can check that out here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: `ToString()` is missing in the CartItem to have an adequate display in list and grid.

Comment: @OlivierRogier The grid displays the individual properties of the `CartItem`, so there is no need for a `ToString()` override.

Comment: Indeed for the gridview. There is a litlte error in my comment. But what is displayed the listview without the tostring?

Comment: I was mislead by the last screenshot which doesn't include the listbox, but if the OP wants to use a listbox as well, an override of `ToString()` is a good way to set the displayed text of an object.

Comment: The last screenshot is for adding items to inventory/database xml
The third screenshot is for getting items from inventory and checks out items
i edited my post please check it out

Comment: public override ToString()  // For displaying the Name in a listbox
    {
        return Name;
    } this gives me an error

Comment: @KeithShirogane I forgot to add the return value of the override. I updated the answer. Next time, mention what the error is you get. The message "I have an error"  doesn't provide any information to solve it.

Comment: The Override is fine now but sir  the  GetNewID()  does not exist in the current context.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write:

```
dataGridView2.Rows[idx].Cells["ID"].Value = item.ToString();
```

Assuming that the type of the items in the list implements the adequate overrided method else you may implement it or use a embedded value wrapper if you can't.

Since the list display correctly the strings, it was already done.

Here's what you want to do can look:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsAppTest
{

  public partial class FormTest : Form
  {

    public FormTest()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }
```

```
    private void FormTest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      listBox1.Items.Add(new CartItem { ID = 1, Name = "Item 1", Quantity = 10 });
      listBox1.Items.Add(new CartItem { ID = 2, Name = "Item 2", Quantity = 20 });
      listBox1.Items.Add(new CartItem { ID = 3, Name = "Item 3", Quantity = 30 });
      listBox1.Items.Add(new CartItem { ID = 4, Name = "Item 4", Quantity = 40 });
      dataGridView2.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
      dataGridView2.Columns.Add("ID", "ID");
      dataGridView2.Columns.Add("Name", "Name");
      dataGridView2.Columns.Add("Quantity", "Quantity");
    }
```

```
    private void ActionAddToCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if ( listBox1.SelectedItem != null )
        foreach ( CartItem item in listBox1.SelectedItems )
        {
          int index = dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
          dataGridView2.Rows[index].Cells["ID"].Value = item.ID;
          dataGridView2.Rows[index].Cells["Name"].Value = item.Name;
          dataGridView2.Rows[index].Cells["Quantity"].Value = item.Quantity;
        }
    }
```

```
    private void ActionClearCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();
    }
```

```
  }
```

```
  public class CartItem
  {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
      return Name;
    }
  }
```

```
}
```

Next you can use the @Stefan answer if you want to use bindings on a List for example.

I recommand using an ADO.NET DataTable with BindingSource to be able to work fine with the listview and the datagridview items without having UI and UX problems like editing.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in InventorySystem.exe

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'InventorySystem.CartItem'.

Comment: If now you use DataTables, you don't need this answer and the CartItem display wrapper pattern. You only need to bind the datagridview as well as the listview to your datatables from your dataset and you will be fine. So this answer dos not match the original question anymore. I recommend [Beginning C# 2005 Databases](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Beginning-C-2005-Databases.productCd-0470044063.html): this is a great and simple step-by-step book to learn ADO.NET and bindings.

Answer (score -1):

```
        if (listBoxContacts.SelectedItem != null)
            foreach (string item in listBoxContacts.SelectedItems)
            {
                int A = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                // dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[textBox1.Text].Value = item;
                dataGridView1.Rows[A].Cells[0].Value = textBox1.Text;
                dataGridView1.Rows[A].Cells[1].Value = textBox3.Text;
                dataGridView1.Rows[A].Cells[2].Value = textBox4.Text;
                dataGridView1.Rows[A].Cells[3].Value = textBox5.Text;
                dataGridView1.Rows[A].Cells[4].Value = textBox6.Text;

            }
```

Comment: Improve your Code Only Answer by explaining what this code does and why this approach solves Op's Problem.